# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b3' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import turtle
import random
import pygame
print("")
print("")
print('''Здравствуйте, это игра "Легенда о Сабине"!
Ваша задача побеждать монстров и спасти принцессу Сабину!
Она в заключении у злого мага Гаргамеля!
Удачи воин!
==========================================================''')
imia=input("Ведите имя вашего героя: ")

h=100
resh='Меню'

b=3
b1=0
b2=b1+1
b3=50

u=1
u1=0
u2=u1+1

d=50
day=1
def stat():
    print('---------', resh ,'---- ',imia, '-- день ',day,'---------')
    print('-Здоровье ', h)
    print('-Броня',b,'%', b1,'ур')
    print('-Урон',u,u1,'ур')
    print('-Деньги',d)
    print('------------------------------------------------------')
def menu():
    stat()
    print('''Ваши действия (Напишите нужное действие):
    -----------------------
    Магазин
    Карта
    Дом
    -----------------------''')
    resh=input("Напишите действие: ")
    if resh=="Магазин" or resh=="магазин":
    stat()
    print('''------------------------------
    Броня''',b2,'ур',b3,'''монет
    Оружие
    Зелья
    ------------------------------''')
    resh=input("Напишите раздел: ")
    if resh=="броня" or resh=="Броня":
        if d>=b3:
            b1=b1+1
            print('''Прокачка успешно завершена!
            Теперь твоя броня''',b1, "уровня")
            d=d-b3
            b3=b3*2
            b=b*2
            back=input("Пиши назад: ")
            if back=="назад" or back=="Назад":
                menu()
            else:
                print("Недостаточно денег..")
    elif resh=="Карта" or resh=="карта":
        stat()
    elif resh=="Дом" or resh=="дом":
        stat()
    else:
        print("")
        print("")
        print("-----------------Не понимаю!-----------------")
        print("")
        print("")
        menu()
menu()
```

Ошибка полностью:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\zelda.py", line 75, in <module>  
    `menu()`   
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\zelda.py", line 46, in menu  
    Броня''',b2,'ур',b3,'''монет  
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'b3' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Это `if back=="назад" or back=="Назад":` можно заменить на `if back.lower() == "назад"`. Это относится и к остальным подобным проверкам

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проблема в [области видимости](https://python-scripts.com/scope). Переменные Вы объявили в приложении. А используете - в функции.
Или объявите её как глобальную, или передавайте параметром в функцию `menu`.